# How to avoid circular dependency with layouts in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, layout, blazor-server-side

There are three assemblies in a project:

- BlazorServer (Blazor Server)
- Module1.UserInterface (Razor Class Library)
- Module2.UserInterface (Razor Class Library)

Now I added a page layout called `PageLayout` in Blazor Server, which depends on Mainlayout (within BlazorServer).
To apply the layout in Module1.UserInterface and Module2.UserInterface I need to add `@layout PageLayout` on the pages in these assemblies.
However, BlazorServer already has a reference to Module1.UserInterface and Module2.UserInterface, so that would end up in a circular dependency.

That leads me to the following question:
**How can I reference this page layout from within the Module1.UserInterface and Module2.UserInterface?**

Is it possible to have yet another assembly (e.g. Shared.UserInterface) with an abstract layout and then use nested layouts as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-6.0#nested-layouts))?

Otherwise the easiest solution would be to just have one assembly for the UI, but I would rather research if there is another way first.